# Get Firestore data in Flutter just for Logged user

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am a girl new for StackOverFlow and Flutter.
I am dev my first app in Flutter and I connected succesfully login and Signup form with AUTH firebase.
Now I created another form in the app which collect other details from the user, it is an address book.
this address book create a new collection into firestore and in another screen of flutter I want to get these data, but just for the user logged in, at moment I can retrieve the data using streambuilder but I get the data from all the documents in firestore.
I think I need to use something called user_id into my fields to import only the data from the specific user logged.
Any good dev here is ready to help me?
below the user creating...

```
try {
                            final newUser =
                            await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: email, password: password);
                            if (newUser != null) {
                              Navigation..);
                            }
```

this is to create a new collection in firestore

```
void createRecord() async {
    await databaseReference.collection("shippingAddress").add({
      'alias': '$alias',
      'shippingName': '$shippingName',
      'shippinglastName': '$shippinglastName',
      'street': '$street',
      'streetNumber': '$streetNumber',
      'zipNumber': '$zipNumber',
      'phoneNumber': '$phoneNumber',
      'textMessage': '$textMessage',
      'totalQuantity': '$totalQuantity',
      'totalWeight': '$totalWeight',
    }).then((value) {
      print(value.documentID);
    });
  }
```

now I need to get this above collection but just for the user logged and I used this code:

```
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('shippingAddress').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data please Wait');
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 350,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                    elevation: 15,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Card(
                            color: Color(0xfffeaf0d),
                            child: Container(
                                height: 40,
                                width: 40,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.local_shipping,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 25,
                                )),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            snapshot.data.documents[index]['alias'],
```

With the code above I get all the data into the widget but not for a specific user.
here the get code

```
class CollectData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CollectDataState createState() => _CollectDataState();
}

class _CollectDataState extends State<CollectData> {

  String phone, wifeName, preferredLocation;

  _CollectDataState({this.phone,this.wifeName,this.preferredLocation});


  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getData() async* {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    yield* Firestore.instance.collection('shippingAddress').document(user.uid).snapshots();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context,) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        return Column(
          children: [
            Text(phone),
            Text(wifeName),
            Text(preferredLocation),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I got A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a new document, you can use the `userId` as a document id:

```
void createRecord() async {
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
 await databaseReference.collection("shippingAddress").document(user.uid).setData({
      'alias': '$alias',
      'shippingName': '$shippingName',
      'shippinglastName': '$shippinglastName',
      'street': '$street',
      'streetNumber': '$streetNumber',
      'zipNumber': '$zipNumber',
      'phoneNumber': '$phoneNumber',
      'textMessage': '$textMessage',
      'totalQuantity': '$totalQuantity',
      'totalWeight': '$totalWeight',
    }).then((value) {
      });
  }
```

Then when using the `StreamBuilder` you can retrieve data from the logged in user, create a method that returns a `Stream`:

```
   Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getData()async*{
     FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
     yield* Firestore.instance.collection('shippingAddress').document(user.uid).snapshots();
  }
```

inside the `StreamBuilder:

```
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

Comment: can I ask you if you can write me a full code to see what is wrong with mine? please.

Comment: Into the VOID " createRecord" I got error on FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()
:A value of type 'Future<FirebaseUser>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'.  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'FirebaseUser'.
and: print(value.documentID); I got This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

Comment: Yes! now createRecord works pretty nice, I have edited question and added getData that return error please check, dont worry about documents collection I just changed. but I cant get them into widget

Comment: all of those `String phone, wifeName, preferredLocation` are null

Comment: I added; Text(snapshot.data['phone']), as widget and it works

Comment: Hi what I have to do to create an exception if no data available?
I got Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: documents